# regex error : raise error, v # invalid expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a variable `device='A/B/C/X1'` that is commented out in another file. There can be multiple instances of the same device such as `'A/B/C/X1@1'`, `..@2` and so on. All of these devices are commented out in another file with a prefix `*`.

I want to remove the `*` but not affect similar devices like `'A/B/C/X**10**'`.

I tried using regex to simply substitute a pattern using the following line of code, but I'm getting an `InvalidExpression` error.

```
line=re.sub('^*'+device+'@',device+'@',line)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the asterisk since it has a meaning in regex syntax:
`line=re.sub(r'^\*'+device+'@',device+'@',line)`.

Escaping the variables you use to construct the regex is also always a good idea:
`line=re.sub(r'^\*'+re.escape(device)+'@',device+'@',line)`

Comment: Or put a r in front of your regex string

Comment: For the record it has a special meaning in markdown too OP. That's why you had random italics and bolded text all over the place.

Comment: @Emaro That will not be sufficient since it will only disable unescaping of backslashes in that string, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_all(text):
    if text in ['*']:
        text = text.replace(text, '')
    return text

my_text = 'adsada*asd*****dsa*****'

result = "".join(map(replace_all, my_text))
print result
```

Or

```
import re
my_text = 'adsada*asd*****dsa*****'
print (re.sub('\*', '', my_text))
```